# $a\in X$. Show that the stalk $\mathscr{F}_a$ is isomorphic to the stalk of $\mathscr{F}|_U$ at $a$ on the topological space $U$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification, sheaf-theory

This is exercise 3.24 from [Gathmann's notes](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2014/chapter-3.pdf).

> Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a sheaf on a topological space $X$, and let $a\in X$. Show that the stalk $\mathscr{F}_a$ is a local object in the following sense: if $U\subset X$ is an open neighborhood of $a$ then $\mathscr{F}_a$ is isomorphic to the stalk of $\mathscr{F}|_U$ at $a$ on the topological space $U$.

**My attempt:**

Define the ring isomorphism: 
$$\overline{(V,\phi)}\mapsto \overline{(V\cap U,\phi|_U)}$$
for any open subset $V\subset X$, that contains $a$.

1. It is well-defined. If $(V,\phi)=(V',\phi')$, then $\phi=\phi'$ on some neighborhood of $a\in W\subset V\cap V'$. Thus they agree on $W\cap U$.
2. We see that it is surjective trivially, because for any $\overline{(V,\phi)}$ in $U$, $V$ can also be considered as in $X$, together with the function $\phi$ defined on it.
3. We show that it is injective. Suppose a function $\phi$ represents the zero function in $\mathscr{O}_{U,a}$, i.e., it is zero in a neighborhood of $a$. Here I am confused. **In the case $X$ is not irreducible, can we say that the preimage has to be $0$? Or can we shrink this open neighborhood until it is in $U$?**

Thank you for any help!

Also, I am self-learning this subject, sometimes I suspect whether my proof is completely nonsense. **If someone could help verify the above proof** it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For the injectivity, if $\overline{(V\cap U,\varphi_{|U})}=0$, then $\varphi_{|U}$ is zero in a neighborhood of $a$ contained in $V\cap U$. So $\overline{(V,\varphi)}$ is also zero and injectivity follows. You don't have to assume $X$ irreducible. By the way, the proposition is also true for sheaves of sets, so maybe you should prove the injectivity without assuming you are dealing with rings.

Comment: @Roland: Thank you, I see! I am pretty sure the author meant for rings in this problem though. Since all the definitions and theorems before that problem are dealing with rings. And he has a remark after this problem that titled "sheaves for other categories". So my proof for 1, 2 are correct then? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, they are correct. Well, of course we can restricts to some sheaves, but rings are way too restrictive for purpose in algebraic geometry or in topology. At least sheaves of abelian groups then (note that this is all you use in the above proof).

Comment: @Roland: Thank you! I see that. But so far this (rings) is the only way I learned about sheaves. I would be curious to see if you could write an answer for the general case. (I am not sure what it means by isomorphic sets, for example.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested in the comment, this is the proof in the case of a sheaf of sets.

The map $\overline{(V,\phi)}\mapsto\overline{(V\cap U,\phi_{|V\cap U})}$ is well-defined and surjective. This is done in the original post in the case of a sheaf of rings, but the proof never uses rings and works perfectly for sets.

Let us show that it is also injective. So assume $\overline{(V\cap U,\phi_{|V\cap U})}=\overline{(V'\cap U,\phi'_{|V'\cap U})}$. This mean that there is a neighborhood $W\subset V\cap U$ and $V'\cap U$ such that $(\phi_{|V\cap U})_{|W}=(\phi'_{|V'\cap U})_{|W}$. But this means that $\phi_{|W}=\phi'_{|W}$. So $\overline{(V,\phi)}=\overline{(V',\phi')}$ and the map is indeed injective.